# Как убрать ограничение на количество записей в таблицу phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, xampp

Доброго времени суток, форумчане!

Столкнулась с проблемой:

В моей таблице порядка миллиона строк (1 288 429). При попытке добавить ещё строки программа вылетает. Я предполагаю, что всё-таки есть ограничение на число добавляемых строк в таблицу, однако не знаю, где это можно изменить. Смотрела конфиги разные, там ничего похожего не нашла.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти эти ограничения и как их изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Миллион строк не так много. Даже при 15 и 20 миллионах строк все работает.
Вылетает программа? Конкретнее пжлст. А если через майадмин добавлять строку?

Можно попробовать посмотреть explain'ом что происходит.

Comment: проблема была в другом, нужно было покопаться в коде приложения. Сейчас всё впорядке, в таблице уже 20 000 000 и нет никаких ограничений на добавление.